# Ajax success is not called after JsonResult

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to add the record to DB using `Ajax` and get the data back from `JsonResult` if success, in order to call the function further, but somehow always land in the error: `parseerror`. However, the record is inserted in DB.

Here is my post method:

```
$("body").on("click", "#btnAdd", function () {
        var txtTermName = $("#txtTermsName");
        var txtAlternativeTerms = $("#txtAlternativeTerms");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Administration/AddTerm",
            data: '{name: "' + txtTermName.val() + '", alternatives: "' + txtAlternativeTerms.val() + '" }',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (r) {
                var row = $("#tblTerms tr:last-child");
                if ($("#tblTerms tr:last-child span").eq(0).html() != "&nbsp;") {
                    row = row.clone();
                }
                AppendRow(row, r.Name, r.Alternatives);
                txtTermName.val("");
                txtAlternativeTerms.val("");
            },
            error: function(textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
            }     
        });
    });
```

And my controller `JsonResult`:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AddTerm(Term term)
{
    this.SaveTerm(term);
    return Json(term);
}
```

Any comment or suggestion is appreciated

**UPDATE**

`Json(term).Data` contents:

```
-       Json(term).Data {Models.Term}   object {Models.Term}
+       ChangedBy   
        Description null    string
        ID  27  int
        Inactive    false   bool
        Name    "sdfgdsgf"  string
        SynonymsList    "sdfgdsgfdsgsdgf"   string
+       Updated {09.08.2018 10:00:50}   System.DateTime
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: What does the browser network tab tell is being returned for the POST?

Comment: Probably not related, but that is an ugly fragile way of generating the data - just use `data: { name: txtTermName.val(), alternatives: txtAlternativeTerms.val() }, and remove the `contentType` option

Comment: @tolik if you ever see `[object Object]` then it's the browser hiding what it actually is (most likely you've done an `alert(textStatus)` or, worse, `alert("textStatus: " + textStatus)`.  You can't combine string with an object, so just always `console.log("textStatus", textStatus)` (note the comma, not a `+`)

Comment: @mjwills, basically the status is : `200 OK` and the  `term.GetType() = {Name = "Term" FullName = "AppNS.Models.Term"}`. If I do  `Json(term).GetType() `, then obviously  `{Name = "JsonResult" FullName = "System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult"} `

Comment: @mjwills `{readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}`

Comment: Comment out `dataType: "json",`. Does that make it go into the `success`? If so, what is `console.log(r);`?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an exception is being called somewhere after your database save call (I take it the SaveTerm method does more than just save the item?) resulting in an error page being returned instead of JSON - hence the parse error.

Try adding a Try { } Catch { } to the action and I reckon there will be an exception caught from the SaveTerm method.

Comment: and/or step through the code to ensure it's getting to the `return Json` (it could also be the json serialise is failing)

Comment: @Milney, tried to surround this.SaveTerm(term); with try-catch, but no issues there.

Comment: @tolik Hmm, do you have any DateTime types in your Model type?? Maybe it is converting a date incorrect, possible due to regional settings

Comment: @freedomn-m, what do you mean by step through? I have put a breakpoint on return and the Data property of the returned result corresponds to the term

Comment: @tolid The JSON result should have a value property with the actual JSON, post that into your question and we can see if it is valid

Comment: @Milney, there is a property with Datatype (called Updated). As of the Value property, I dont see it, I see only Data property.

Comment: @tolik yes okay sorry the Data property - it should have the JSON STring that will be sent - post that

Comment: @Milney added the contents of Data property